# Can I have different Minecraft mods in different worlds?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

Is it possible for me to have different Minecraft worlds with different mods?

For example, say I have one world with Pixelmon and a few other mods (improved furnaces, craftguide and timber), and I would like another world with say, FTB mod, but **not** Pixelmon.

Is this possible?

Comment: you'll need different mc folders, check out [multiMC](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1000645-multimc-43-windows-linux-mac/) which enables this easily

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is doable, but you will need, as ratchet freak pointed out, a separate copy of minecraft for each set of mods. multiMC is one way to do that, but if you [upgrade to the new launcher](http://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/articles/1163345-new-minecraft-launcher), you can create custom profiles, each with a separate set of mods, to make it even easier (see [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/122246/how-to-install-mods-for-the-new-minecraft-launcher) for details, since the new launcher adds a couple of steps to the modding process).

Also, once the new launcher is more mature, and Mojang finally get around to providing official mod support, the whole process of switching mods on and off will probably get even easier.

Comment: Mojang has explicitly stated that the plugin (mod) API will make them be per-world. (No exact citation handy but I think it was in the Minecon 2012 talk.)