# How can I have multiple copies of the same version of a mod side-by-side?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I know that you can add more folders inside your mods folder for other forge versions. For example:

- `Roaming\.minecraft\mods\1.10.2`
- `Roaming\.minecraft\mods\1.7.4`

But I want two files of the same version.. so

- `Roaming\.minecraft\mods\1.10.2`
- `Roaming\.minecraft\mods\1.10.2`

but that will not work.

That is why I got two different forge for the same version and tried. I renamed the folders to the forge version name and still both don't work..
I wanted a 1.10.2 recording folder and 1.10.2 Pixelmon folder but this is not working

Comment: Related: [Can I have different Minecraft mods in different worlds?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/122299/28182)

Answer (score 4):

Not 100% clear what the request is, but sounds like maybe you are after multiple instances of Minecraft, giving you the option to have different mod bundles even across same Minecraft versions. MultiMC would be the answer in that case, https://multimc.org/