# Scala library error when launching Forge for Minecraft 1.6.4

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-forge

I just updated my Minecraft launcher to 1.6.4 but I am facing some problems using it. It runs correctly without any mod but when I launch with Minecraft Forge, whenever I try to launch it I get the following error and the game won't launch.

> Gave up trying to download http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.10.2/scala-library-2.10.2.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'
>   Job 'Version & Libraries' finished with 2 failure(s)!

What is the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install mods for the new Minecraft 1.6.1+ launcher](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/122246/how-to-install-mods-for-the-new-minecraft-1-6-1-launcher)

Comment: @MBraedley I don't think any answers there help this. My guess is they've installed a non-recommended build. Some builds, the Forge team messed up the Scala library support.

Comment: @SvenSidedDie thank's for the support and i have installed the recommanded version of the forge

Comment: Akash: what build of Forge are you using? It will say in the launcher to the right of the Play button: "Ready to play Minecraft 1.6.4-Forge9.11.1.XXX" or similar, but instead of "XXX" it will be a three-digit number. That's the build. What build does your launcher say you have?

Comment: my build is 9.11.1.916

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about support for a modded version of Minecraft.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first time that Forge runs it needs to download a bunch of code libraries that match your system. One of these is failing to download for some reason, and it's required for Forge to run. I can download it in my browser though, so whatever is preventing Forge from downloading it automatically isn't preventing me from downloading it manually.

So here's how you may be able to fix it:

1. [Download the library manually](http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.10.2/scala-library-2.10.2.jar). (That's the same link as in the error message in your question.)

   This will download a file named `scala-library-2.10.2.jar`. Save it somewhere where you can find it again.
2. Open your .minecraft folder, then navigate to **libraries** → **org** .
3. Inside the **org** folder, create the folder `scala-lang`.
4. Open the new **scala-lang** folder and create the folder `scala-library` inside it.
5. Open the new **scala-library** and create the folder `2.10.2` inside it.
6. Open the new **2.10.2** folder. Find `scala-library-2.10.2.jar` wherever you saved it in step 
   (1), and put it inside **2.10.2**.
7. Now double-check that all the folders are named *exactly* as above, with no extra letters, and no spaces before or after each folder name. Any errors will prevent the next step from working. Fix any naming errors you find before moving on.
8. Run the launcher and start Forge. When it gets to the point where it used to try downloading Scala, it should find the library you just manually installed and keep going.

Comment: Sir, really thank you as i was not able to play Minecraft since the 1.6 version was released due to this problem and i could not find any help on Google so thank you. Sir i wanted to ask that what the screen look's like after installing forge cause in previous version of Minecraft it showed the deatail of the forge in lower left corner of the home screen but there is nothing like that here.

Comment: @Akash In the bottom-left corner it should say "Minecraft [version] / MCP [version] / FML [version] / Minecraft Forge [version] / X mods loaded, Y mods active", and there should be a "Mods" button under the "Multiplayer" button. If it doesn't, then the Minecraft version you launched doesn't have Forge installed. Check the profile editor to make sure you have *Use version: release 1.6.4-Forge9.11.1.916* selected.

Comment: yeah forge is not working game is running but no forge no mod button there is no release 1.6.4-Forge9.11.1.916 there is only release 1.6.4 and one having forge is release 1.6.2-Forge9.10.0.789

Comment: @Akash Have your run the installer for Forge #916?

Comment: yup 1-right click on the java file   2-install the client  3--message appear's installed correctly  4--run's Minecraft and select forge profile  5--poof forge not working

Comment: @Akash What's in your .minecraft/versions/ folder?

Comment: there are five subfolder's  1.5.2, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.6.2-Forge9.10.0.789, 1.6.4

Comment: @Akash Okay, Forge #916 just isn't installing for some reason. I don't know why. :(

Comment: yeah i tried it re installing but it didn't worked  anyway thank's for the help

Comment: So what is the full path? I have `org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.10.2` and placed the files in there and it doesn't work.

Comment: @AaronFranke Are you trying to run Minecraft 1.6.4 like in the question this is answering? If not, the version of Scala is likely different and goes in its own version number’s folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at http://files.minecraftforge.net/fmllibs/ you see that the link to bcprov-jdk15on-148.jar is renamed to bcprov-jdk15on-148.jar.stash

Same thing with scala-library.jar
It's renamed to scala-library.jar.stash

Forge is looking for the link without the .stash
No wonder Forge has issues with the download.

Comment: The log file shows that it's not attempting to download Scala from that location at all. It's attempting to get the version on `repo.maven.apache.org`.

Comment: Where do I put these files once downloaded?