# Using Curse to install Minecraft mods

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

As the "computer guy" in the family, I am the default person to ask computer questions.  My 10 year old nephew wants to install a Minecraft mods and asked me how to do it.  I have never played Minecraft, so I am unfamiliar with it.  I did some quick searches and it appears Curse supports Minecraft.  I used Curse back in my Warcraft days and found it easy to use for installing mods.

Is Curse as easy to use for Minecraft as it was for Warcraft?  If I get it installed on their computer remotely, will it be easy for a 10 year old to use?

Comment: @fbueckert I dont see any correlation between my question and the possible dulpicate

Comment: Sometimes we try to step back from the question as asked and focus on the problem instead.  In this case, the linked question is asking about the same problem.

Comment: or in other words we at the SE network strive to avoid the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) and drill down to solving the problem rather than blindly following a solution

Comment: @ratchetfreak Im well aware of XY, Im a top 40 contributor on 2nd largest SE site.

Comment: This is [currently being discussed on chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12319089#12319089).

Comment: I have voted to close this question because as now written, it appears to be about how easy is it to use a piece of software. This is very opinion-based, and not a good fit for this site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Curse cannot install Minecraft mods**. What it can do is manage texture packs and saved worlds, as well as giving you the ability to try out the Snapshot builds that are released periodically. This Snapshots are installed separately from your regular installation.

If you don't want to have to go through complex configuration (you often need to unpackage and repackage the files to install mods), then you can use [Skydaz](http://www.skydaz.com/) to get one-click mods installers. Hopefully, those work for you.

Alternatively, we have already have a question that covers [manually installing mods for Minecraft 1.6.1 onwards](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/122246/how-to-install-mods-for-the-new-minecraft-1-6-1-launcher).

Comment: Considering that the Minecraft launcher or the game itself can do almost everything mentioned in the first paragraph, Curse doesn't really bring anything useful to the table.  Personally, I'd avoid it for Minecraft.

Comment: This answer seems no longer true, curse can install mods now.