# Minecraft Corrupt

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In attempting to install a mod for Minecraft,I have accidentally deleted the **bin** folder in .minecraft .If someone could tell me how to fix that,thanks.I've tried deleting/redownloading the game,but that does not work either.

Comment: The launcher should download the files it is missing again. I believe there is a check mark you can put forth to force it to do an update in the bottom left corner, but this is a comment not an answer because I can not verify that right now.

Comment: Yes,but it doesn't do that.The launcher downloads every file but the bin file,and it takes a quite a long time for the launcher to even start the game after this incident.

Comment: Just try moving/renaming the .minecraft folder and running the launcher again, then copy bin back over. Yes, it's lazy, but man is it SO much faster

Comment: Worry not; as of the new launcher (Minecraft 1.6.1+), the bin folder is no longer used. If you need help installing mods, check out [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/122246/how-to-install-mods-for-the-new-minecraft-launcher).